# Swift Retain Cycles and Closures

Tags: ios, swift, retain-cycle

I have tried to do a lot of research on understanding retain cycles.  I can't seem to find anything on my examples though.  I do know that if i set a property to a closure then a retain cycle happens and need to use weak or unowned.  But i have 2 examples that I would like to know if they are done correctly: Thanks in advance, I have tried to see if they are on stackoverflow already but couldn't find anything.

**Simple animations**

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self, duration: 5, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations:    { [weak self] in
    self?.setNeedsDisplay()
    return
}, completion: nil)
```

**Animations with an array**

```
for imageView in self.townImages {
    UIView.transitionWithView(imageView, duration: 0.3, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.getImages()[count++])
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

In both of these examples `self` is a subclass of `UIView`. I would just like to know that I am doing it correctly or if I should be using the imageView as weak reference too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these will create retain cycles since the block is not attached to `self`. Additionally, retain cycles with guaranteed life span aren't the worst thing in the world.

Let's consider some examples. *(sorry, my swift isn't particularly strong, so I'm going to revert to obj-c.)*

---

```
- (void)doSomething:(void(^)())block {
  self.block = block;
}

// elsewhere
  [self doSomething:^{
    self.someProperty = 5;
  }];
```

This creates a retain cycle because `self` is referenced (not weakly) within a block to which `self` holds a reference.

---

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self duration:5, options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
} completion:nil];
```

This does not create a retain cycle because the `animations` block is sent off to the system -- your `UIView` subclass doesn't hold a reference to the block.

---

**Side note**: You shouldn't need to have a `return` at the end of your closure, but I guess swift is ridiculous and tries to be "helpful". Also, I'm not sure you need to call `self.setNeedsDisplay()` during the animation since it should be doing that itself...

Comment: So does that mean that it only creates a retain cycle if my class holds a reference to the block? or if the `UIView.transitionWithView` method also did it would create a retain cycle? So in other words if either class held a reference to the block then it would create a retain cycle?

Comment: also the return in the first example was because in swift if only one statement was made in a closure it automatically returns that value, and in this case the closure expected a return value of Void so I use the return statement to return void and not the result of `self?.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: Yeah, odd but true: in Swift you *do* need the return in this case. One of the oddities of the language's different rules for one-statement closures. (And the current version of the compiler it throws an irrelevant and completely misleading error message if it's not there, too...)

Comment: Holding a reference to a block does not always create a retain cycle. An object holding a reference to a block that references the object does create one.

Re: `return`: WELL THAT'S JUST SILLY. ...

Comment: @IanMacDonald It strikes me as a little odd, too, and is definitely a bit of a gotcha. On the other hand, it does have some benefits for writing quite neat, terse expressions with closures, along with a few other new bits of syntax (e.g. `let result = array.filter { $0 > 5 }`, stuff like that.) So I can see some of the appeal.